# Interface implementation callbacks - management

Tags: c++11

I've been thinking of creating some callbacks by interface inheritance. The question is, should I take, say, a shared_ptr, a unique_ptr, or a raw pointer? I don't want to define the memory management of the derived class because, well, they should have their own undefined memory management.

Comment: well, the question is too general. you may use share_ptr, but unique_ptr doesn't fit.

Comment: there are some pitfalls with share_ptr. I mean cyclic links between them. so in the class which will call the callback interface you might need weak_ptr. As a rule approach based on raw pointers is the most comprehensible. It is used in COM, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::function`?

Your use sounds like exactly what std::function (well boost::function) is perfect for.